# How do I change this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I want to change the way that content is displayed on my website:

```
var FNav = {
init: function() {
    $("a[href*=#]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]) {
            FluidNav.goTo($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]);
        }
    });
    this.goTo("home");
},
goTo: function(page) {
    var next_page = $("#"+page);
    var nav_item = $('nav ul li a[href=#'+page+']');
    $(".page").fadeOut(500);
    next_page.fadeIn(500);
```

How do I change this JavaScript, so I can have a proper back button functionality?

**What I have tried** (Unsuccessfuly). These are the solutions that I tried but without changing the javascript above. That is why I think none of them seem to work.

- Using the History.js method described here:
  https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ I fill out all the steps and
  enter the scripts to the header, however only the URL in the URL bar
  changes when I click on a link. When I click the Back button, the URl
  changes accordingly, but content doesn't load. When I enter a URL in
  the URL bar, I get sent to the home page.
- Ajaxify and Gist method
  described here: https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify Achieves the
  same as above, same issues as well
- Davis.js method described here:
  https://github.com/olivernn/davis.js Achieves nothing upon completion
  of the installation instructions. No change.
- jQuery BBQ Plugin method
  described here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/
  Achieves nothing, no change upon loading the .js file in the header
  of the website.
- I read this article and understood it:
  http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: What's wrong with how the back button works as standard, the proper way? Any reasonable browser will support anchor navigation, too.

Comment: I hate developers that touch the user expected behavior.... Grrrr

Comment: You should test for `$(this).attr("href").indexOf('#')===0` instead. Your test right now would also, for example, match Wikipedia links with a hashtag to link to a specific section in the document. Or any other external link with a hashtag.

Comment: It would help if you elaborated what you mean by "proper back button functionality".

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals Thanks, I mean that when I go: 
/#services -> /#special -> /#superspecial then by using the browser back button I can go:
/#special -> /#services

Comment: @MildlyInteresting Hi, thanks for the answer. So I tried replacing the if($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]) line with your suggested  $(this).attr("href").indexOf('#')===0 line and there hasn't been any change. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: No. If it keeps working it's perfect. It just wont work anymore in case you post an external link with a hash in a document with this script running. Because you wouldn't want to scroll to #definition on your page, which might doesn't exist, when clicking on a wikipedia link.

Answer (score 0):

The back button does not magically work. You need to code and listen for the event change!

In history.js, [it shows you right on the front page](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/):

```
// Bind to StateChange Event
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you couldn't get Davis.js to work for you?  Perhaps open an issue on the GitHub page.

If you want to use hash based routing with davis you need to include the [hash routing extension](https://github.com/olivernn/davis.js/blob/master/lib/extensions/davis.hash.js).  You then just need to include it in your page after davis.

The following setup should then allow you to handle routes

```
Davis.extend(Davis.hash)

Davis(function () {
    this.get('/:page', function (req) {
        FluidNav.goTo(req.params.page);
    })
})
```

Assuming you have links in your page with the following

```
<a href="#/page_1">Page1</a>
<a href="#/page_2">Page2</a>
```

Davis will take care of handling the back button for you, so that if you click on the link for Page1 and then Page2, clicking on the back button will navigate to Page1 again.

If you have any problems please open an issue on the GitHub page detailing what you have and what isn't working and I can take a look at it.